# How to use vanity address in Phantom? (n00b question)

Tags: solana-keygen, vanity-id

I’ve created a new wallet using a vanity address via the “solana-keygen grind” command and I have the json output file, but how do I use json files with a Phantom wallet?

I was under the impression that all wallets needed to keys, one derived from a seed phrase - have i got this wrong?

I’ve tried to refer to the Solana Docs but they may as well be written in Latin (if you’re not a Dev).

Does anyone have simple “go here, click here” instructions of how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a gif showing how to import a private key into phantom wallet
[image: import private key to phantom]

Answer (score 1):

### Wallets vs Private keys

You are mostly right about a Private key being part of a wallet. A "wallet" is actually both the Private Key and a Public Address.

The private key is the secret part that should never be shared since it will "sign" all the transactions and actually control the tokens in the wallet. When people refer to their "wallet keys", that is their private key.

The public address (aka wallet address) is the addresses that you will see people sharing and viewable via block explorers. This is totally safe to be shared around with no security concerns.

A single private key can be used to generate multiple public addresses. But a single public address can only be signed for by the single private key.

### Addresses Generated via the CLI

While you can import any private key generated from the Solana CLI using any web wallet (like Phantom or Solflare), for most people it is not recommended.

The main reason is that the `solana-keygen grind` command uses a [different derivation path](https://nick.af/articles/derive-solana-addresses) than most web wallets. In a nutshell, this means that the wallet "address" (aka "PublicKey") of your wallet will not match the one you generated. So for most people, there is no point to add it into a web wallet.

### To Import a Private Key into Phantom browser extension wallet

But if you still want to import your generated keys, here is how:

- open the browser extension
- click the "burger menu" button in the top left
- click the pencil "Manage Accounts" button on the bottom left
- click the "Add/Connect" wallet button at the bottom
- then "import private key" button
- finally, copy and paste in the contents of the JSON file you generated with the Solana CLI (it should look something a bunch of numbers wrapped with `[` and `]`)

Answer (score 0):

To get the private key, you have to open the json file (in notepad or notepad++ on windows or equivalent) and copy the list of numbers it gives you. Someone above showed how to import this private key, did that end up working? These steps worked for me. This thread is not yet marked as answered.